# Show that the set $\omega = \mathbb{C} \setminus \lbrace A \rbrace $ is simply-connected.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

$A= \Omega = \mathbb{C} \setminus  \lbrace \lbrace x \epsilon \mathbb{C}, \vert x \vert \geq 1 \rbrace \cup \lbrace iy: y \epsilon \mathbb{R}, \vert y \vert \geq 1 \rbrace$

for the problem we use the definition:

A connected open subset $\Omega$ of the complex plane is simply-connected if the set shows that the set $\mathbb{S_{2}} \ \phi^{-1} (A)$ is connected. It is enough to check that $\mathbb{S2} \setminus \phi ^{-1} (A)$ is arc-connected.

But I do not know how to prove that  $\mathbb{S2} \setminus \phi^{-1}(A)$ is arc-connected.

Thankyou!!

Comment: It's truly amazing how terrible this formatting is. I can't even tell what $A$ is from what you've written. In the title $\omega=\Omega=\Bbb C\setminus A$, but in the body of the post you write $A=\Omega$

Comment: Do you mean you remove those points $z=x+iy$ for which either $|x|$ or $|y|$ (or both) are at least $1$? [If so the first set should be $x \varepsilon \mathbb{R}$]